# How to hide soft keyboard after requesting keystroke with kivy in Android?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, hide

I used the kivy website example to create an app for Android that listens for a keystroke string.  It works great, but as I am using it with scanners and scales the soft keyboard that pops up becomes unnecessary.

I have tried all the different config settings as well downloading the app Null Keyboard.

Update:
What is interesting is that as soon as the keyboard is removed the App does not take the input anymore.  Why would that be?

Code:

```
    def _get_the_keyboard(self):
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(
            self._keyboard_closed, self, 'text')
        if self._keyboard.widget:
            # If it exists, this widget is a VKeyboard object which you can use
            # to change the keyboard layout.
            pass
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        if self._keyboard != None:
            self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
         # Keycode is composed of an integer + a string
        # If we hit escape, release the keyboard
        if keycode[1] == 'escape':
            keyboard.release()
        elif (keycode[1] == 'shift' or keycode[1] == 'rshift') and text != None and keycode[0] != 44 and keycode[0] != 46:
            self.is_shift = True
        elif self.is_shift and (keycode[1] != 'shift' or keycode[1] != 'rshift'):
            print(keycode[1])
            self.is_shift = False
            if keycode[0] == 46:
                self.key_input = self.key_input + str(chr(62)).upper()
            if keycode[0] == 44:
                self.key_input = self.key_input + str(chr(60)).upper()
            if keycode[0] == 92:
                self.key_input = self.key_input + str(chr(124)).upper()
        elif (keycode[0] > 47 and keycode[0] < 58) or (keycode[0] > 96 or keycode[0] < 123) and keycode[1] != 'enter'\
                and text != None and keycode[1] != 'shift' and keycode[1] != 'rshift' and not self.is_shift and keycode[0] != 44 and keycode[0] != 46 and keycode[0] != 301:
            self.key_input = self.key_input + str(text).upper()
        elif keycode[1] == 'enter':
            plyer.notification.notify(title="Capture Data", message=str(the_key), app_name=self.the.name,
                                              timeout=2,
                                              ticker='New Incoming Notification', toast=True)
            if self.scrn_name == 'firstscanpage':
                if self.ids.emp_first_scan_key.text == "":
                    self.scan_weight_ticker()
                    self.ids.emp_first_scan_key.text = self.key_input
                    self.i = 0
```

How can I disable or hide the soft keyboard on requesting the keystroke `on_key_down` without removing the keystroke listener?
Would it help to bind the keyboard to different widgets after each keystroke

SOLVED IT:
Null Keyboard App does solve the problem.  After activating Null Keyboard in the settings you have to choose it by pressing "spacebar" and choosing it.  No more soft Keyboard! Of course this is not the best solution.

Comment: Instead of using request_keyboard, just bind to `Window.on_key_down` etc.

Comment: @Inclement Thank you for the information.  I tried the following ```self._keyboard.on_key_down(key=self.on_key_down)``` where ```self.on_key_down``` is a function that takes the ```key``` argument.  Also I tried ```self._keyboard = Window``` and then bind to the callback ```self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)```, but I get a ```TypeError``` to many positional arguments.  Also, ```self._keyboard = Window.on_key_down(
            self.on_key_down)``` did not give any result. Can you please elaborate how I can bind the ```Window.on_key_down```?

Comment: Use `Window.bind(on_key_down=some_function)`. It sounds like at least one of your attempts was correct, except you bound a function that didn't expect that right number of arguments. Use something like `def func(*args, **kwargs):` to accept any arguments, then expect those to see what you received.

Comment: @Inclement Thank you very much.  Only ```*args``` was necessary in the end.  And ```*args``` gives a ```<class 'tuple'>``` that has 4 elements.  Elements are [0]: ```<class 'kivy.core.window.window_sdl2.WindowSDL'>``` which has alot of interesting looking properties and mehods;  [1]: ```<class 'int'>``` which is the ascii table decimal number; [2]: ```<class 'int'>``` not sure what the number represents as I thought it would be the hex of ascii but it does not match the ascii table hex column; [3]: ```<class 'str'>``` is the keyboard value in string form.  Once again thank you.

Comment: @inclement Your suggested bind method is correct.  No soft keyboard and the App reads the keystroke.  Thanks!  If you make your bind method the answer, I will mark it as such.